# Normalization of Dirac bispinors

Tags: quantum-field-theory, dirac-equation, spinors, dirac-matrices

Let $u_\lambda(\vec{k})$ and $v_\lambda (\vec{k})$ be solutions of the following equations
$$(\not k-m)u_\lambda(\vec{k})=0$$
$$(\not k+m)v_\lambda(\vec{k})=0$$
Suppose that $u_\lambda(\vec{k})^\dagger u_\sigma(\vec{k})=\frac{\omega(\vec{k})}{m}\delta_{\lambda\sigma}$ and $v_\lambda(\vec{k})^\dagger v_\sigma(\vec{k})=\frac{\omega(\vec{k})}{m}\delta_{\lambda\sigma}$, where $\omega(\vec{k})=\sqrt{m^2+\vec{k}^2}$. I am trying to show that it implies that
$$\bar{u}_\lambda(\vec{k})u_\sigma(\vec{k})=\delta_{\lambda \sigma} \qquad  \quad \bar{v}_\lambda(\vec{k})v_\sigma(\vec{k})=-\delta_{\lambda \sigma}. $$

My question is: How to do it without taking any special representation of Dirac matrices and without doing it in special reference frame (i.e. rest frame)? Moreover, I don't assume transformation law for this bispinors (so I really do not assume they are bispinors in the proper sense). The only thing which I assume is that Dirac equations for $u$ and $v$ are satisfied and we know anticommutation rules for $\gamma$-matrices and we have given above normalization for $u^\dagger u$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: you want to calculate
$$
\bar u_s(\boldsymbol p)\gamma^\mu u_{s'}(\boldsymbol p)=\ ? \tag{1}
$$

Being a covariant object, the vector index in the *r.h.s.* can only be provided by $p^\mu$, and therefore
$$
\bar u_s(\boldsymbol p)\gamma^\mu u_{s'}(\boldsymbol p)=a_{ss'} p^\mu \tag{2}
$$
(why is $a$ independent of $\boldsymbol p$?)

To find $a_{ss'}$, contract both sides of this expression with $p_\mu$, and use the equation $\not pu=mu$.

Now let $\mu=0$.

Ok, let us add some more details:

> If you contract both sides of $(2)$ with $p_\mu$, you get \begin{equation}m\bar u_s(\boldsymbol p)u_{s'}(\boldsymbol p)=a_{ss'}m^2\end{equation}
>  On the other hand, if you let $\mu=0$ in $(2)$, you get \begin{equation}u^\dagger_s(\boldsymbol p)u_{s'}(\boldsymbol p)=\omega_{\boldsymbol p}a_{ss'}\end{equation}
>  From these two equations, you should be able to solve for $\bar u_s(\boldsymbol p)u_{s'}(\boldsymbol p)$.

Comment: Shouldn't be $u^\dagger$ instead of $\bar{u}$ ?

Comment: @mikis no, you get $u^\dagger$ when you let $\mu=0$ (because $\bar u\gamma^0=u^\dagger$)

Comment: Ok. I still have one question : you used fact that $\bar{u}\gamma^\mu u$ is a covariant object. How to see it using only knowledge that $u$ satisfy given Dirac equation ? I think to do it we need a transformation law for bispinors.

Comment: @mikis the Dirac equation is covariant, and therefore so are its solutions (for example, the classical wave equation $(\partial_t^2-\nabla^2)y(x)=0$ has solutions $y=\exp(\omega t-\vec k\cdot\vec x)$, which are covariant, as you already know).

Comment: The $u$ bispinors are covariant by definition. This has nothing to do with the fact that they satisfy the Dirac equation. We could have chosen different phases and normalizations for them and all covariant transformation properties would cease to be true. The point is that $u(\vec p)$ is DEFINED as appropriate boost of $u(0)$.

Comment: @Blazej that's one valid definition of $u$, but not the only one. Most introductory textbooks define the $u,v$ spinors as any basis in the space of spinors, where the $u$ satisfy $pu=mu$ and the $v$'s satisfy $pv=-mv$. Further constraints, such as $S_zu(0)=\pm 1/2$ suffice to uniquely specify these objects, but to solve Dirac equation, any basis is as good as any other (your definition is useful when one wants to study the particle content of the theory, but unnecessary if one *only* wants to solve the Dirac equation, say, as a classical wave equation). (Needless to say, your def. is better).

Comment: So, we need to assume that our $u$'s are chosen in a covariant way ? Anyway, if not for $u$ maybe it is possible to somehow obtain covariance of $\bar{u}\gamma^\mu u$ only from Dirac equation (without this additional assumption of $u(p)$ being a boost of $u(0)$ )? It is the main point of my question : Is the Dirac equation enough to do it ?

Comment: "To find  ass′" ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

Comment: I agree that if you specify enough bilinear covariants then the u's will be specified essentially uniquely. But not completely because phase is ambiguous (it doesn't affect values of bilinear covariants). However it will show up if you consider bispinors which are linear combinations (interference terms).